# What can I use for proof of title in a background check?

Tags: united-kingdom, background-check

I'm undergoing a background check (UK) and I'm afraid that I don't have a formal contract stating the title to which I was promoted (Team Lead) last year at my current job.

However, I do have official emails, my first contract, and a payslip for both the first month I was employed and the last month, therefore, I have proof of employment, but not of the new title.

The only proof of this title I have is a LinkedIn post in which my name is mentioned as the team lead, the entry in the HR system with my data and job title, and emails to the team announcing me as the new team lead.

I assume I couldn't use these emails as proof given they're sent to my professional address (is this correct?), **but would my entry in the HR system and the public LinkedIn post by my company be valid as proof of the new title?**

PS: Please notice that I was planning to resign only after the BG checks, so I asked the third party doing the BG check (HireRight) not to contact my former employer (there's this option in their form).

Comment: Have you been asked for proof?

Comment: Yes, as I was filling the form I had to fill in the proof of employment and title if I checked the checkbox to ask HireRight not to contact my current employer.

Comment: What are you imagining they expect as proof if not the items you listed? Those should be good for any reasonable auditor.

Comment: @Corey I said I couldn't use emails though because those are addressed at my professional email, all I can use is the LinkedIn post which mentions my name as a "team lead" and a screenshot from the HR system with my position, which is easy for a malicious agent to fake if they wanted to. Do you still think those would be enough?

Comment: I do not understand your reason for why the emails cannot be used. If anything, the proof is strengthened by them being sent to your professional address. A malicious agent could fake a lot of things. They are looking at the sum of the findings and matching that up against whatever else they find out and what they already know about you. They are factoring in the likeliness that you would risk doctoring something like your title. You are analyzing this more than they are.

Comment: This is one of those things that nobody can help you with. You need to go ask whoever is asking you for proof and ask what sort of proof they need. My guess is they need your previous employer to provide the proof with a phone call (by them) and all you'd need to do is leave the POC information for them to reach out to your previous employer.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this.

It is very rare for hiring managers to *actually* confirm references. They usually take the employment history stated in the resume at face value. They will only consider checking it a useful use of their time if your employment history seems too good to be true.

And *if* they end up confirming your employment history, then they will do so by contacting your past employers directly. If those choose to lie for whatever reason, then there is not much you can do about it. You won't get a chance to provide your side of the story or deliver "proof" that they were lying. You will just get the standardized rejection letter.